# Efficient calculation for log(exp(x)), where x is a really big value

Tags: python, pytorch

Imagine I have a tensor `x=[1000,2000,3000]`. I need to calculate `[log(e^1000)`,`log(e^1000 + e^2000)`, `log(e^1000+e^2000+e^3000)]`. If I use `torch.log(t)`, where `t` is a big values like 1000, `exp(t)` is `inf` and the `log` of that becomes `inf`. Do you have any suggestions to find the solution for this? I assume that I need to use torch.logsumexp but I don't know how to make that work in case that I need to calculate the cumulative sums.

I need to avoid for loops because I am using a huge dataset.

Comment: `torch.logcumsumexp`? https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.logcumsumexp.html

Comment: You can simplify this expression algebraically before you ever compute anything. For example,  `log(e^1000) == 1000`, and `log(e^1000 + e^2000) == log(e^1000*(1+e^2)) == 1000 + log(1 + e^2)`.

Comment: @slothrop this is great, thanks for sending the link

Comment: @chepner log(e^1000 + e^2000) == log(e^1000*(1+e^1000)) == 1000 + log(1 + e^1000). Your factorization is wrong here

Comment: Indeed, thanks for catching that. (And depending on how much accuracy is needed, `log(1+e^1000)` is basically `log(e^1000) == 1000`.)